# Call sed to replace a string stored in a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed, quoting

I want to expand a variable in `bash` with `sed` or `awk`. This variable is an array.

For example, the script must delete strings contained in array.
I tried

```
ARRAY1=(
string1
string2
string3
)

sed -i '/${ARRAY1[@]}/d'  /etc/file
```

and

```
ARRAY1=(
string1
string2
string3
)

for i  in ${ARRAY1[@]} ;do sed -i '/$i/d'  /etc/file;done
```

but none works, `sed` does not expand the variables.
How can I do this?

Comment: the second solution would work if you used "" instead of '' as elbarna said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution, 
using `""` instead of `''`.

Comment: It is true that "" will expand your variable for illustration try echo ${ARRAY1[@]}, echo '${ARRAY1[@]}' and echo "${ARRAY1[@]}" ... That said, just changing the quotes would not create the desired behavior as it would also print each element of the array in a separate lines and would at best not match what you intended at worse garble the sed command where it would cause a parsing error of the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
array1=(
  string1
  string2
  string3
)
sed -i -e/$^array1/d file
```

Would delete all the lines that match any of the regex in `$array1`.

Or you could do (any Bourne-like shell):

```
regexps='string1
string2
string3'
grep -ve "$regexps" file
```

Or, to search strings, add the `-F`:

```
grep -F -v -e$^array1 # (zsh)
```

or:

```
strings='string1
string2
string3'
grep -F -ve "$strings" # (any shell)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use sed instead use egrep -i -v (-i case insensitive -v does not match pattern):

```
egrep -i -v "$(echo ${ARRAY1[@]} | tr ' ' '|')" /etc/file
```

the expression

```
echo ${ARRAY1[@]}
```

because it has no quotes will not print new line making a space delimited string with all the strings in the array.

```
tr ' ' '|'
```

will replace all spaces with \| (or) for the grep expression which will build the pattern for your grep command.

Now if you insist on using sed there are a couple of options one of which would look something like:

```
 sed -i $(echo ${ARRAY1[@]} | sed -e 's:\w\+:-e "/\1/d":g') /etc/file
```

This will create a separate -e "/stringFromArray/d" for the sed base sed command

NOTE: make sure that there are no spaces or "/$|" in the strings in your array. If there are depending on what solution you try it could get in the way.

Comment: `tr ' ' '\|' does not replace spaces by `\|` but by `\`. `tr` replaces characters, not strings. Not quoting `${ARRAY1[@]}` is fundamentally problematic as it will break if there is whitespace or `\[?*` in any of the array elements. While the fundamental idea of using grep here is good, the execution needs to be rethought.

Comment: Good point I was in a hurry and grep does not interpret | properly but egrep or grep -E does. so changed it to egrep and the tr to replace space with | and voila.